# How to make my result String 1000 characters long using LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to  limit my result string to 1000 characters when I use `LISTAGG`.

Here is my example query:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(EMPLOYEE_NAME,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_NAME) AS NAMES
FROM TB_EMPLOYEE;
```

If NAMES size is more than 1000 characters long, I just want only 1000 characters and ignore the remaining.

Comment: Can your current query get more then 4000 characters (or 32k in 12c), throwing an error? And do you want to stop mid-name, or after the last name that completely fit in? The value you are producing doesn't seem very useful though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way to trunc string to 1000 characters is:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(LISTAGG(EMPLOYEE_NAME,', ') WITHIN GROUP 
    (ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_NAME), 1, 1000) AS NAMES FROM TB_EMPLOYEE;
```

If you want to stop conacatenating EMPLOYEE_NAME on length condition in runtime, you should write your own PL\SQL proc, LISTAGG concats all data.

Okay, if you want to make it in single query, try this. First of all, calc overall lengths of all concatenating strings plus 2 for ', ' symbols:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, SUM(LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_NAME)+2) over (ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_NAME) FROM TB_EMPLOYEE;
```

Then call LISTAGG for this subquery:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(EMPLOYEE_NAME,', ') WITHIN GROUP 
(ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_NAME) AS NAMES FROM (
  SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, SUM(LENGTH(EMPLOYEE_NAME)+2) over 
  (ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_NAME) slide_length FROM TB_EMPLOYEE )
WHERE slide_length < 1000;
```

Comment: Thank u.. you ans only valid,when limited number of rows in a TB_EMPLOYEE. but if table contains 1 lakh records it will throgh an error.